# C# Round Scientific Notation Value

Tags: c#, rounding, scientific-notation

I have a small double value that is formatted in scientific notation.  When I display the value it is displayed in the format 1.34423E-12 with 5 digits after the decimal.  I would like to round this value so that it displays like 1.344E-12.

Is there a built in way to round a scientific notation value to x number of decimals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a format string like

```
double d = 1.34423e-12;
string formattedValue = d.ToString("E3");
```

Here `"E"` means to use scientific notation (with capital "E", use `"e"` if you want a small one...) and `3` stands for three digits after the decimal point.

You can look at [Standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) at MSDN to see other options. The documentation for the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) method also contains useful information about formatting values.

**EDIT**

If you want more flexibility, you can use [Custom numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx). Using these you can e.g. also specify the number of digits used for the exponent like

```
d.ToString("0.000E0"); // -> Results in "13.344E-12" instead of "13.344E-012"
d.ToString("0.000E0000"); // -> "13.344E-0012"
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for.  Is there any way to prevent "E-12" from changing to "E-012"?

Comment: Yes that's possibble too: see the edit in my answer.